# Sorting list of items according to another fixed list

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm very beginner in C#.

I have a List of

```
private List<String> mXMLProdcutsIDs = new List<String>();
```

mXMLProductsIDs is like

```
{"megapack", "levelpack","bikepack"}.
```

Sometimes I get `another list which is in random order`, `{"megapack", "levelpack","bikepack"}`
I would like to resort that list according to the `mXMLProductIDs` list order

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because it changes question significantly. But if you have some custom class instead of string, then answer will be same, except you need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods of your custom class

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Would you give an example please, I'm very beginner in C# :)

Comment: Here you can find sample of [GetHashCode implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode). Implementing Equals is pretty easy - just compare fields of objects. Just try searching samples - you will find a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use index of string in original list to define items order:

```
var result = anotherList.OrderBy(s => mXMLProdcutsIDs.IndexOf(s));
```

Shorten version:

```
var result = anotherList.OrderBy(mXMLProdcutsIDs.IndexOf);
```

Keep in mind, that result will be `IEnumerable<string>`. You can use `ToList()` if you need to save results in list.

---

Another option (if you don't have duplicated items in another list):

```
var result = mXMLProdcutsIDs.Intersect(anotherList);
```

Comment: What if the other list "has" some strings that can be compared in addition with some other fields ? how would the comparison work ?

Comment: Can you clarify what is *comparing in addition with some other fields*?

Comment: If I have the list that needs to be sorted as List<XMLProduct> for example, but it has a String that can be compared with the XMLProducts ID list of Strings.