# Sorting list with by a property name according to a fixed set of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, sorting

My goal is to sort a list by the `Name` property according to a fixed set of strings `preferedOrder`.

Consider:

```
class MyClass
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

List<string> preferedOrder = List<string> { "AA", "BB", ... }
```

I've looked on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961133/sorting-list-of-items-according-to-another-fixed-list) and ended up with:

```
return list.OrderBy(item => preferedOrder.IndexOf(item.Name));
```

My question is how to achieve the same result only if the `preferedOrder` is implemented with `string[]`? like:

```
string[] preferedOrder = new[] { "AA", "BB", ... }
```

I'm asking because its a performance critical code, and I assume implementing the `preferedOrder` with array will get better results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If array is *long*, I suggest turning it into a `Dictionary<string, int>` since dictionary is faster (`Dictionary[...]` has `O(1)` time complexity vs. `O(N)` for `Array.IndexOf`):

```
   string[] preferedOrder = new[] 
     { "AA", "BB", ... }

   Dictionary<string, int> map = preferedOrder
     .Select((value, index) => new {value, index}) 
     .ToDictionary(item => item.value, item => item.index);
```

Then

```
  return list.OrderBy(item => map[item.Name]);
```

Or if `item.Name` can be *abscent* in `map`:

```
  // -1 - abscent values will be on top
  return list.OrderBy(item => map.TryGetValue(item.Name, out var v) ? v : -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with a:

```
return list.OrderBy(item => Array.IndexOf(preferedOrder, item.Name));
```